# How to use Domain Arichitecture with ASP .NET Identity (circular reference between projects)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using the domain architecture and facing following issue when using Identity from .NET framework.
To use usermanager etc. in my controllers, I did place the Identity classes in the front-ent/API layer. All my entity classes are in the domain layer (data access layer takes care of db access).
So far, so good.
But now, I do have a class Company which has a one to many relationship to the AppUser: IdentityUser class. That works, if I place the Company class in the API layer. However, I need also to use the Company class in the domain layer. That doesn't work as I cannot reference the API layer from Domain layer (circular reference).

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

N.

Comment: What prevents you from putting your Company class in your domain layer?

Comment: Also, I think the [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site may be a better fit, since you seem to have an architecture/design problem with your code.

Comment: Well, it is because the API layer references the domain layer. So, the AppUser class (which has to be in the API layer because of the Identity) is not available in the domain layer. I did already a lot of projects with this setup. It works pretty well and separates the code. However, in this project I need a "parent" for the AppUser.

Comment: @imsmn as I read it, the `AppUser` class is what stops them. This could also be brought into the domain layer, but that 1) brings a dependency on Asp.net identity to the domain layer which doesn't feel completely right 2) splits the implementation of the identity database context across two projects.

Comment: When you say "domain architecture," are you talking about "Domain Driven Design" - from the book by Erik Evans?